# CSS Variables don't work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-variables

I am designing a new blogger Template. I want to make it easy to change the whole template color at the same time by changing the value of the variable , so I used these lines:

```
:root {
  --bg-color: #fff;
  --url-color : #000;
  --main-color : #2daeeb;
  --main-hover-color : #2ca1de;
  --alt-color : #ff6347;
}
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work in Edge browser, even though I used the prefix:

```
-webkit-
```

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is and what you are trying to achieve. CSS variables aren't available in Edge: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables. What is the question you are trying to answer?

Comment: I don't believe Edge supports CSS variables at this time.

Comment: Both [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables) say that this feature is unsupported in MSIE and Edge.

Comment: That said, I don't understand why people think your question is unclear. It isn't and it shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Me neither. There are two things clear about this question: 1) it's asking about custom properties 2) it's an XY problem ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CSS variables are not supported by IE nor will they ever be.

**Update:**

CSS variables are supported in Edge since EdgeHTML 15 (packaged with Windows 10 version 15063, available since March 2017.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) under Browser Compatibility.

Also, [the W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/).

---

As an alternative you can use a CSS pre-processor to compile your CSS using variables in the way you describe.

[Docs on Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

[Docs on Less](http://lesscss.org)

Comment: what is the alternative ?

Comment: There are CSS preprocessors that can accomplish your goal such as Sass/SCSS and LESS.

Comment: @peterhany Check out this Sass guide http://sass-lang.com/guide